# Ruby, Sinatra and Passenger config on Apache

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger

This is potentially a simple question but I wanted to ask to avoid running around in circles.

I have installed ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu and have set up passenger to run with Apache 2.2 on the machine. I am getting the following error when I view the site:

```
Permission denied - log/sinatra.log
```

I have changed the permissions for the log directory, but still no luck. The full trace from passenger can be seen on the site page: http://monkeh.me/

Does anyone know if/what I've done wrong or what's happening?

Many thanks

**EDIT**

I have discovered that the site runs well using WEBrick on port 4567 on the production server, but the same code errors using Passenger. I have added to show exceptions for errors, so am now getting the following:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
file: resource.rb location: block in attributes= line: 332
```

You can see this here: http://www.monkeh.me/?url=http://www.google.co.uk

Any ideas? Please help :)

Comment: The linked site doesn't show any passenger trace. Does that mean you solved the problem?

Comment: Hi Frost. The issue _may_ have been to do with the rack gem. I installed that and the homepage of the sinatra app works, but I get a 500 error when going to subsequent pages, for example: <http://monkeh.me/jirey> which is the short URL to taker you to Google.com. I've been unable to find ways to trap 500 errors to see what's actually going on.

Comment: If you run the site locally, are you getting the same error?

Comment: No, not at all. I'm running it on a Mac 10.6.8 without Apache (using shotgun and webrick for testing).

Comment: ...and I assume the logging works properly locally as well? In that case, it's kinda hard to know what's the actual problem.

Comment: Have just run another test on the prod server, but this time using WEBrick on 4567 and not Apache / Passenger. It works this way, so something must be wrong with the Passenger install..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new issue with the nil class was due to not finalizing the classes properly. I needed to add the following after the models were loaded:

```
DataMapper.finalize
```

Thanks to @Frost for his continued help within the comments.